# Import lxml module cause PyImport_ImportModule failed

Tags: python, html, c++, import, lxml

I wrote python test code which uses the module `lxml`.

I want to call `foo` in c++.

It will fail in step `PyImport_ImportModule` if I add the `from lxml import html` but works well when I remove it

Test.py

```
import os
import sys
import requests
from lxml import html     #it will cause failed

def foo():
    host = "http://www.baidu.com"
    s = requests.session()
    res = s.get(host)
    return res
```

c++ code:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')");
PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("Test"); //failed
if (pModule == NULL || PyErr_Occurred()) 
{
   PyErr_Print();
}
PyObject* pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
PyObject *pFunHi = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "foo");
PyObject *ret = PyObject_CallFunction(pFunHi,NULL);
Py_DECREF(pFunHi);
Py_Finalize();
```

The error msg is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\Test\Debug\Test.py", line 4, in <module>
from lxml import html
File "E:\python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: Unable to find the specified module。
```

how to use lxml module correct?

Comment: You should check if `pModule == NULL` or if an error occurred. See my recent [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745999/embedding-python-in-c-segmentation-fault/38791595#38791595) if it helps.

Comment: You should verify that lxml has been correctly installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it , it's the lxml installer's fault.

I download version 3.6.0 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.6.0 (lxml-3.6.0.win32-py2.7.exe) ,because it had no version 3.6.1 installer. and it caused the question i mentioned.

so I download a new whl installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml (lxml-3.6.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl) and update the old one. All is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will crash at

```
PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("Test");
PyObject* pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);  //will crash
```

if `pModule == NULL`. You should check the return values, for example

```
if (pModule == NULL || PyErr_Occurred()) {
   PyErr_Print();
}
```

The question states that the filename for the module is test.py but then in the code the module name is Test i.e. `PyImport_ImportModule("Test")`. The case should match.

To verify that lxml is correctly installed:

```
import lxml # does not fail if lxml has been partially installed
import lxml.etree # fails if C extension part of lxml has not been installed
```

If the latter import fails, lxml may not have been installed correctly.

Comment: **I Comment you follow, I really don't know how to use markdown in comment, i test it many times ,it not takes effect. **

Comment: I test "import lxml.etree"  ,  it's failed . "import lxml" is ok.  I install lxml use msi package. maybe as you say, the c extension part of lxml has not been installed. I'm new to python, i don't know what c extension part is, and how make sure the c extension installed , can you give some suggestion

Comment: Can you test what happens with `PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.insert(0, './')");` instead of sys.path.append?

Comment: It's strange that it works well some time，and  suddenly failed...  It display error like the before, "DLL load failed" . I don't know what happened...

Comment: Hi, I remove lxml 3.6.0 msi which download from pypi and install a new one from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml,  version 3.6.1.  All is ok